# How to pass image Star Rating to Jpeg image using PEL Exif library

Tags: php, wordpress

For image description and subject we passed the metadata using this code

```
$pelIfd0->addEntry(new PelEntryAscii(PelTag::IMAGE_DESCRIPTION, $titleval));
$pelIfd0->addEntry(new PelEntryWindowsString(PelTag::XP_SUBJECT, $subtitle));
```

the above code working properly i need to pass the star rating value using pel exif like above code we tried using different class and different arguments but its not working. This Image shows the output exactly we are working

[image: This Image shows the output exactly we are working]

Answer (score 0):

First, refer to [this git request](https://github.com/lsolesen/pel/pull/70/files)

They are making a suggestion for inclusion into the PEL source files. It has not been approved as far as I know.

I made the suggested changes to my local PEL source copies, followed by this addition to my code. It has been working well.

```
$ifd0->addEntry(new PelEntrySShort(PelTag::RATING, 5));
```